# Maven (m2e) does not update the JRE in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

In my `pom.xml` I declared the Maven compiler plugin as followed:

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But m2e does not update the JRE that is used for this project. It still uses Java 1.4. Installed is the JDK 8 update 5. This is the only version that is installed. I am on windows.

Did I miss something? On my Mac I have the same settings and there it works.

**Update**

I set up a new virtual Windows machine on my Mac and did clean installs of Java 8, Eclipse Kepler SR2 and Maven. Now Maven sets the correct JRE, but Eclipse gives me errors like "Syntax error, X is only available if source level is 1.5 or greater". Project specific settings for the compiler are enabled by m2e and set to 1.7. I also bumped the compiler plugin version to 3.1. I am totally confused. Please help me!

Comment: Try updating the compiler plugin to 3.1; 2.5.1 is very old. Additionally, you might need to upgrade Eclipse to a version that knows about Java 8 (Luna? I'm not using 8 yet).

Comment: When you do an `Update Project...` do you get any sort of error message?  Or does eclipse claim the project is updated and still won't actually update the java version?

Comment: Have you tried right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project? By the way, Eclipse doesn't support java 8 yet, you need to install a plugin from Marketplace

Comment: The latest Kepler release has a patch for Java 8 (it works on my Mac). I get no error message from Eclipse, it just remains Java 1.4. I will try to update the plugin.

Comment: Have you tried changing Window-Preferences-Java-Compiler-Compatibility level?

Comment: Yes, the lowest selectable level is 1.7 which is selected. However, I thought m2e handles the JRE selection for the project?! On both my Mac and Windows machine 1.7 is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Java 8 support for Eclipse and Maven via the *Eclipse marketplace*:

```
Help > Eclipse Marketplace > Search for "java 8"
```

Then install the following two plugins:

- Java 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2
- Java 8 support for m2e for Eclipse Kepler SR2

You need to restart Eclipse during the installation.

Comment: You are right. There are eclipse packages that have the patches already applied. I was using such a package on my Mac but downloaded the normal package on Windows :/